# ReactJS - Not able to edit the input field after i bind the data from this.props.reducer.result.firstName(Used redux)

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Please note I'm  Material-ui react js component for my Textfield. I have not used redux-forms.

I have declared the onchange listerner and state

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    firstName: null,
    };
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {
    // This is reducer function to get my data from server. I'm getting data and able to display it to my element.
    // I'm using redux for my data layer.
    this.props.getuserDetails(userId);
}
```

I'm not sure how to update the input element value using state as well as the value i received from props via reducer function.

```
handleInputChange (event) {}
    this.setState({
    firstName: event.target.value
    });
}
```

inside my render function.
Textfield displays the user firstname. But its not allowing me to edit the field. Because i have bind the props.reducer directly.

```
<TextField name="firstName" onChange={this.handleInputChange} floatingLabelText="First Name" value={this.props.reducer.result.firstName}/>
```

How do i bind the data from dispatcher/reducer. and also accept user input to edit the first name. 
later i can update it in server

I'm struck with this issue. any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `componentDidMount`, `this.props.getuserDetails(userId)` function will set the props again, you should set the state in `componentWillReceiveProps`. and use `this.state.firstname` instead of `this.props.reducer.result.firstname`

code:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    if(this.state.firstName != nextProps.reducer.result.firstname)
    {
        this.setState({
            firstName: nextProps.reducer.result.firstname
        });
    }
}
```

this will update the `props` to `state` and use `this.state.firstname`

```
<TextField name="firstName" onChange={this.handleInputChange} floatingLabelText="First Name" value={this.state.firstName}/>
```

Comment: Thank you. it worked. Earlier i tried to set state values in the below method and failed to do so. componentWillReceiveProps(){]

Answer (score 1):

You're right. You can't update your input element using `setState()` since it's value propagated through and bound to props.

Depending on what you're trying to achieve, there are different solutions available..

1. Update props by dispatching an action each time your input changes: e.g.:

   ```
   handleInputChange (e) {}
       // NOTE: I just made up this action
       this.props.setUserDetails(e.target.value);
   }
   ```
2. Set initialState from props and bind the input to state (this is considered an anti pattern, though it's OK if you make clear that it's only used for initial state. Also, react will not update the value of the input field after it has been rendered):

   ```
   componentDidMount() {
      this.setState({ value: this.props.value })
   }

   handleInputChange (e) {}
      this.props.setState({ value: e.target.value });
   }
   ```
3. Merge props and state whenever props change.
4. ...

But anyway, as said before, it depends on what you're trying to do.

[Here's a more detailed answer](https://discuss.reactjs.org/t/how-to-pass-in-initial-value-to-form-fields/869/5)